# Amount can only be increased by 20% - paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have integrated the Paypal subscription option into my site. My problem is when I try to upgrade the subscription it shows an error in Paypal:

> Amount can only be increased by 20%

Subscription amount is $0.25

Upgrade amount is $0.59

How can i increase the percentage of the amount?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this myself.  It's a pretty ridiculous limitation.  Rumor has it that even PayPal Pro has this limitation, although I haven't personally verified.  Looks like there is no way around it other than to instruct users to cancel their membership and re-subscribe with a new membership.

Comment: p.s. They confirmed this limitation on twitter: https://twitter.com/lprichar/status/488527414474330112 and also mentioned a billing agreement as another option, but that doesn't work for my situation.